# Tosca string operations module not replacing double quotes

Tags: tosca

I was working on a requirement where i want to replace a " with \" using TC String Operations.
Following are the parameters i am passing to TC String oprations module.

Value : {B[matching_pattern]}
Operation: Replace,Global
Pattern : "
ReplaceBy : "
Reault : matching_pattern     action mode :buffer

This method is working for every other character except a "

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The way of identifying double quotes is different in tosca..u can use string replace function
{stringReplace[ABC"]["][]}

Comment: Try out this one